# How to display custom attribute in related product in related.phtml

Tags: php, html, magento, magento-1.8

I need to display custom attribute in related product.

I have tried get value of custom attribute in related product from related.phtml file.

app/design/frontend/base/default/catalog/product/list/related.phtml file.

But not getting print custom attribute. My custom attribute name is "testattr".

```
 foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>

// Start tried Displaying custom attribute

echo "Testattr::" . $_item->getTestattr();

// End tried Displaying custom attribute



            <li class="item">
                <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="product">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(50) ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                    <div class="product-details">
                        <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a></p>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
```

Any one can help me? i need to display custom attribute value in related product right side sidebar in default magento.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$productId = $_item->getProductId();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$yourCustomeAtt = $_product->getTestattr();
echo $yourCustomeAtt;
```